# Why can I use std::unordered_map with references but not with std::stack?

Tags: c++, reference, stl, stack, unordered-map

I have `std::unordered_map<char, Argument&>` and it works fine, but when I try to declare `std::stack<Argument&>`, I'm getting the following error:

> In template: 'allocate' declared as a pointer to a reference of type 'ArgumentParser::ArgParser::Argument &'

Comment: Probably because a reference cannot be re-bound.  Fortunately, [`reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) can be re-bound!

Comment: What is the original and underlying problem that you think will be solved by using references in containers? Normally one would store object themselves in the containers, and then use references to those objects. Perhaps your use-case might be better solved with `std::shared_ptr<Argument>`? Perhaps it can be solved some other way? Always please ask about the underlying and actual problem directly, and then tell us the solution you have in mind, and we can tell you if it's feasible or not, and possibly give you other and maybe better solutions.

Comment: In short, your question is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: The elements in your `std::unordered_map` are of type `std::pair<char, Argument&>`, which is not a reference type.